# Cloud External Git properties refresh

Tags: git, properties, cloud

I have deployed my Spring boot application which is a SOAP web service on cloud. I have configured a spring cloud config server and connected it to my properties file residing on Git.

How can I make my application understand a change in a property from the properties file residing on Git?

Answer (score 0):

Your client app (`SOAP` app) would need to connect to the `Config Server`. Once a property file is pushed to a `Git` repo, you would need to send a `POST` request to `http://client-app-host/refresh` and your `@RefreshScope` annotated classes should get re-created with new the property value, for instance, `@Value` annotated class attributes.

Or if you would like for the `@RefreshScope` annotated classes to be "refreshed" without any manual intervention then you would need to also include a message broker for the `Config Server` to send messages to and client apps to listen from. Messages brokers supported by Spring Cloud Config server are: `RabbitMQ`, `Kafka` and `Redis`.

I have blogged about this two scenarios with detailed demo and explanation at:

- [Centralized and versioned configuration using Spring Cloud Config Server and Git](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/09/Centralized-and-Versioned-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-and-Git.html)
- [Refreshable Configuration using Spring Cloud Config Server, Spring Cloud Bus, RabbitMQ and Git](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/02/02/Refreshable-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Spring-Cloud-Bus-RabbitMQ-and-Git.html)